# Create value if missing for this identifier

Tags: python, pandas

I want to solve a problem that essentially boils down to this:
I have identifier numbers (thousands of them) and each should be uniquely linked to a set of letters. Let's call them a through e. These can be filled from another column (y) if that helps.
Ocassionally one of the letters is missing and is registered as NAN. How can I replace such that I get all the required numbers.

```
Idnumber    X      y
   1        a      a
   2        a      a                                                              
   1        b      b
   1        NaN    d
   2        b      NaN 
   1        d      c
   2        c      NaN
   1        NaN    e
   2        d      d
   2        e      e
```

Any given x can be missing.
The dataset it too big to simply add all posibilities and drop dupplicates.
The idea is to get:

```
Idnumber    X
   1        a      
   2        a                                                                    
   1        b      
   1        c
   2        b       
   1        d      
   2        c      
   1        e    
   2        d 
   2        e
```

The main issue is getting a unique solution. So making sure that I replace one NaN by c and one by e.

Comment: With what values are you going to fill that `NaN`?

Comment: IIUC you need to create a dict/series of the ID's and their associated values? you can then do `df['X'].fillna(dict)`

Comment: so the NaNs should be c then e?

Comment: It's clear from the comments that your question is unclear, please define your problem fully with a complete explanation and desired output

Comment: question is messy since you DO NOT mention HOW to fill missing value. It will not be a helper arbitrary choice!

Comment: Sorry, cleared up and expanded the question a bit. The main issue is mentioned at the bottom. The extra column y does not have to be used, but I do have it. I didn't know for sure if it would alter the answer

Comment: Why does the fourth row X become "c" and not "d"?

Comment: I am looking for all unique combinations of IDnumber and x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?  Or does this use too much RAM? If it does use too much RAM, you can use the [chunksize parameter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking) in read_csv.  Then write results (with duplicates and nans dropped) for each individual chunk to csv, then load those and drop duplicates again - this time just dropping duplicates that conflict across chunks.

```
#Loading Dataframe
from StringIO import StringIO
x=StringIO('''Idnumber,X,y
1,a,a
2,a,a
1,b,b
1,NaN,d
2,b,NaN
1,d,c
2,c,NaN
1,NaN,e
2,d,d
2,e,e''')

#Operations on Dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(x)
df1 = df[['Idnumber','X']]
df2 = df[['Idnumber','y']]
df2.rename(columns={'y': 'X'}, inplace=True)
pd.concat([df1,df2]).dropna().drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to prevent cutting up the dataset for this, but I guess it might be the only solution. Guess I would first have to sort by IDnumber to do this in this case ?